# What's wrong with my Facebook app redirect URI?

Tags: facebook, authentication, redirect, uri, facebook-apps

I'm developing an application and I'm configuring the Facebook application.
For the login I'm setting the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs to a working url.

However if I press Save, I get an error message, that says 'This url has bee identified as malicious and/or abusive.' There's nothing like that on the url. It only responds with a json:
    {"message": "The user declined the authorization"}

I've already tried the Facebook Debugger, but it only responds with:
    We can't review this website because the content doesn't meet our Community Standards. If you think this is a mistake, please let us know.

I thought it might be the 401 response status code, but it accepts a different url with the same status code.

I'm out of ideas.

Update: It seems like Facebook thinks my whole domain is malicious, no url with this particular domain can be added to Rewrite URI, nor can be shared by Facebook. I wrote them with the 'Let us know' option. but no naswers so far.

Answer (score 0):

That error response should be pretty self explanatory and since you even confirmed that this URL is blocked you should use the available "let us know" function is the Sharing Debugger if you think it was blocked due to an error.

Comment: Of course I sent them a message with the "Let us know" option. However that's not for support, they MIGHT read my problem, but I wouldn't rely on that.

Comment: That's the only available option unless you want to change that domain/URL completely